# how do I compare dates separated by semicolon in same cell in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison, duplicate

This is my data in column A. I want to compare dates with each other separated by semicolon to see if they all match or not and put the answer in another column saying match or no match. How do I do it?

```
2018-11-01 ; 2018-11-01 ; 2018-11-01 ; 2018-11-01
2018-11-01 ; 2018-11-01 ; 2018-11-01 ; 2018-11-01 ; 2018-11-01 ; 2018-11-01
2018-12-30 ; 2018-12-30 ; 2018-12-30 ; 2018-12-30
2018-11-27 ; 2018-11-27 ; 2018-11-27 ; 2018-11-27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUBSTITUTE to substitute every where the first date exists in the string with `""` and test if you only get `""`:

```
=IF(SUBSTITUTE("; "&A1&" ","; "&LEFT(A1,FIND(";",A1)-1),"")="","Match","No Match")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you for helping. The formula as not working in my spreadsheet for some reason. Here's what I got;

effective date                                                            match or no match?                                                               
2019-01-03                                                                      #VALUE!
2018-11-01 ; 2018-11-01 ; 2018-11-01 ; 2018-11-01     #VALUE!
2018-11-01 ; 2018-11-01 ; 2018-11-01                             No Match
2018-12-30 ; 2018-12-30 ; 2018-12-30 ; 2018-12-30       No Match

Comment: @Mona please edit your post to include more examples, because as you can see, with the ones provided it works.

Comment: Hi Scott, the formula works like a charm. My column had invisible characters and that's why the formula was acting up earlier. Greatly appreciate your help!!

Comment: @Mona please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.